# remainder question for big number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every 2 digit positive integer is repeated 5 times and strung together (ex. 1818181818). Find the remainder when all of these integers are added together and divided by 505

Not sure best way to do it -

Comment: Your question is not well set.

Comment: Final sum you got is not correct. Could you elaborate on how you got this. Also, sum of each digits would be 45*10 in even places and 45*9 in odd places.

Comment: **Hint** $1818181818=18\times101010101$ and $101010101\bmod505=1$

Comment: The sum of the ones digits (including $0$) is $45$ and you do them each $9$ times. The sum of the tens digits (not including $0$) is $45$ which multiplied by $10$ is $450$ and you do each one ten times so $\sum_{n=10}^{99} n = 10*450 + 9*45$.  Alternatively $\sum_{n=a}^b n = \sum_{n=1}^b n -\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}= \frac {b(b+1)}2-\frac {(a-1)a}2= \frac {b^2+b-a^2+a}2$.

Answer (score 2):

If you repeat the two digit number $n=10a+b$ (ie digits $a,b$) five times you get $ababababab$, which is $n\times 101010101$. It is easy to check that $101010101=1\bmod505$. So the sum of all these 10 digit numbers mod 505 is the same as the sum of all two digit numbers mod 505.

$10+\dots+99$ is an AP with sum $45\times109$ (as usual pair the numbers $10+99=109,11+98=109$ etc and multiply by half the number of terms).

It is easy to check that $45\times109=360\bmod505$.

Comment: $$\large \begin{align} &{\rm easy}_1\!\!:\, \bmod {\overbrace{1010}^{\Large 2\,\cdot\, \color{#0a0}{505}}}\!:\ \overbrace{1010}^{\Large \equiv\ 0}\overbrace{1010}^{\Large\equiv\ 0}\color{#c00}1\equiv \color{#c00}1,\ \text{so is} \equiv 1\!\!\!\! \pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{505}}\\[.3em]
&{\rm easy}_2\!\!:\, \bmod\ 505\!:\ \ \  9(5)109 = 9(545)\equiv 9(40)\equiv 360 
\end{align}\qquad\qquad $$

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you. Beautifully clear! I must learn how to do those neat brackets above the line. Ah! It is a mixture of align and overbrace!

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all the units digits of two digit numbers is $9 \cdot 45=405$.  The sum of the tens digits of two digit numbers is $10 \cdot 45=450$, because there are $10$ of each.  The sum of all the two digit numbers is $4905$.  We can check that from the triangular numbers, where the sum of all the numbers up to $99$ is $\frac 12\cdot 99 \cdot 100=4950$ and we subtract the sum of all the numbers up to $10$, which is $45$.  The fivefold repeat multiplies this by $101010101$, giving a total of $4905\cdot 101010101=495454545405$, which is equivalent to $360 \bmod 505$

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward.

A two digit number $10 \le n \le 99$ and if $n = "ab" = 10a + b$ then $ababababab= n(101010101)$.

So the sum of all of these is $\sum_{n=10}^{99} n(101010101)= 101010101[\frac {99*100}2 - \frac {9*10}2]=101010101[4950 - 45]= 101010101*4905$.

And $4905\equiv 4905- 505 \equiv 4400-4040\equiv 360\pmod {505}$

And $101010101 \equiv 1010101010-1010000000 \equiv 10101-10100\equiv 1\pmod {505}$

So the sum $\equiv 1*360\equiv 360\pmod{505}$

.....

As to your error.  You are not summing the digits.  It's badly worded but $\sum {10a+b} = 10*(10\sum a) + 9*\sum b = 4500+9*45 = 109*45$ or put straighforwardly $\sum_{n=10}^{99} = 109*45$  You aren't actually adding the $a$s and the $b$s together.

Answer (score -1):

A mechanistic way to write your initial sum is
$$
S = \sum_{n=10}^{99} \sum_{k=0}^{4} n10^k
$$
Then your question reduces to
$$
S \equiv x \mod{505}
$$

Can you solve this relationship?